# how to make recursive function thats put uppercase letter at first and after this '.' char

Tags: c, string, recursion, uppercase, lowercase

1. The string is a sentence and not just one word.
2. must be recursive.
3. here how I do it for one word. the first function change the first letter. the second function puts lower case in the rest.

Here what I tried:

```
void changeWord(char *str){ 
    if (*str >= 'a' && *str <= 'z')
        *str  = *str - 32;   //stop condition.
    changeRest(str+1);
}


void changeRest(char *str){
    if (*str !=0){   //STOP CONDITION.
        if (*str >= 'A' && *str <= 'Z'){  //if its upper.
            *str  = *str +32; //change it to lower
        }
        changeRest(str+1); //call the new string -1.
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: why not an iterative solution? (the tail recursion will be compiled into an iterative code anyway, so the recursion won't have any performance impact at all, but it looks ugly :) )

Comment: Note: Rather than `*str +32`, use `*str - 'A' + 'a'`.  Avoids the magic number 32.

Comment: its not solving the problem. i need to correct full sentence, only after . I need to put an uppercase.

Comment: Do you want to append a period to the string, or change its last character to a period?

Comment: What I mean is: only after a period character I will change the next char to upper. for examle: if i have this string: "good job. sir" it change the string to: "Good job. Sir"

Comment: @chux Uh... nevermind, don't know what I was thinking. Friday afternoon :) I've posted an answer which hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: yes, of course i meant the first char in the next word. it this case it "2 next chars". sorry.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to know how to fix the case on a single word, or parse and correct an entire sentence? Your code example seems very focused on a single word, but your objections to responses implies the latter.

Comment: And, of course, you realize none of our proposed solutions are suitable for production code. They are all ignorant of locale -assuming English and ASCII, not Unicode and arabic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional argument to your recursive function to signal to it whether it is at the beginning of a sentence.  It makes more sense then to combine your code into a single function rather than two.  For example:

```
void capitalize(char *str, int sentence_start){
    if (*str == '\0') {   //STOP CONDITION.
        return;
    } else if (*str == '.') {
        sentence_start = 1;
    } else if (*str >= 'a' && *str <= 'z') {
        if (sentence_start) {
            *str = *str - 'a' + 'A';
            sentence_start = 0;
        }
    } else if (*str >= 'A' && *str <= 'Z') {
        if (sentence_start) {
            sentence_start = 0;
        } else {
            *str = *str - 'A' + 'a';
        }
    }
    capitalize(str + 1, sentence_start);
}
```

The top level call to that function would pass `sentence_start` nonzero if the first letter is to be capitalized; you could write a wrapper function to do that for you if you don't want to have to do it manually.

Of course, the above assumes that the uppercase and lowercase letters each appear in a contiguous block of character codes, of the same size and in corresponding order, with 'a' (respectively 'A') at the beginning and 'z' (respectively 'Z') at the end.  That's rather U.S.-centric, but it seems to be what your requirements are aiming at.

Comment: Avoiding ctype.h is not such a big deal.  The main thing is to get the structure of the recursive algorithm right.  Answer updated.

Comment: thanks alot its work. finally !! thank you and all the others!!

Answer (score 0):

The functions toupper and tolower in ctype.h are typically implemented like this:

```
char tolower (char ch)
{
  if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z')) 
  {
    ch = (ch - 'A') + 'a';
  }

  return ch;
}


char toupper (char ch)
{
  if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z'))
  {
    ch = (ch - 'a') + 'A';
  }

  return ch;
}
```

Comment: yes its the easy part. but how do i run on the entire string ?

Answer (score 0):

An iterative function would work well here.
Here is a dual recursive solution.

```
#include <string.h>

int my_isalpha(char ch) {
  return (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z');
}

char my_toupper(char ch) {
  if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
    ch = ch - 'a' + 'A';
  }
  return ch;
}

int EndOfSentence(int ch) {
  return !!strchr(".?!\n\v\r", ch);
}

void Sentence_Case(char *src);

static void Normal_Case(char *src) {
  while (*src) {
    if (EndOfSentence(*src)) {
      Sentence_Case(src + 1);
      return;
    }
    src++;
  }
}

void Sentence_Case(char *src) {
  while (*src) {
    if (my_isalpha(*src)) {
      *src = my_toupper(*src);
      Normal_Case(src + 1);
      return;
    }
    src++;
  }
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char s[] = "good job. sir";
  Sentence_Case(s);
  puts(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This addresses all your requirements.

Assumptions:

- The supplied buffer contains a valid C-style string
- The supplied pointer is non-null.
- The presence of a period in the string strictly implies the end of a sentence.
- From the above, no embedded floating point numbers. Thus "pi is about 3.14" is invalid (though this should handle it).
- Character set is the native C one (ASCII, 7-bit)

Code, including helpers

```
// Keep all helpers as functions to avoid side effects of calls
// such as toupper(text++).

unsigned char toupper(unsigned char c)
{
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ? c - ('A' - 'a') ? c;
}

// All characters in the ranges [0,' '] and [0x7f,inf) are either
// whitespace, control characters, or otherwise non-printable.
int iswhitespace(unsigned char c)
{
    return (c <= ' ' || c >= 0x7f)
}

int isalpha(unsigned char c)
{
    unsigned char uc = toupper(c);
    return uc >= 'A' && uc <= 'Z';
}

// Note that identifiers beginning with "str" are reserved 
// by the standard library.

void Capitalize(unsigned char *text)
{
    // Base condition: at the end of the string
    if (! *text)
        return;

    // At the beginning of a sentence. Capitalize the first char.
    *text = toupper(*text);

    // Find the next sentence and recurse
    for (text++; *text && *text != '.'; text++);
    for (text++; *text && iswhitespace(*text); text++);
    Capitalize(text);
}
```